# Why do I get "Segmentation fault" on fread?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, cs50

When I run `valgrind` I get this message

```
==1175== Invalid write of size 8
==1175==    at 0x400923: main (recover.c:37)
==1175==  Address 0x1ffec6e0a8 is on thread 1's stack
==1175==  in frame #0, created by main (recover.c:10)
```

Line 37 is `fread(restored, memSize, 1, mem);`

This is my code:

```
typedef uint8_t BYTE;
#define BLOCK 512

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if(argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Invalid number of command-line arguments..\n");
        return 1;
    }

    FILE *mem = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    if(mem == NULL)
    {
        printf("The file could not be opened..\n");
        return 1;
    }

    fseek(mem, 0L, SEEK_END);
    int memSize = ftell(mem);
    
    rewind(mem);

    printf("%i\n", memSize);


    BYTE restored[memSize];

    fread(restored, memSize, 1, mem);
    fclose(mem);

    // rest of code ...

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How big is your file?

Comment: @Eugene ~3,744 KB

Comment: This `restored` is allocated on stack. So can very well overflow it depending on the system.

Comment: Oh darn never really thought of this, thank you!

Comment: yeah, a 3 MiB could easily overflow the stack. Use `malloc` to allocate a sufficiently large amount of memory

Comment: In general, segmentation fault = you messed up with memory somewhere.

Comment: Pro tip: If you want to read an entire file into memory, you could use `mmap` to do very efficiently.

Comment: To summarize, use `BYTE *restored = malloc(memSize);` [and check for `NULL` afterwards].